# Problems synthesizing MIG 7 series for arty board external DDR3 memory (VHDL)

Tags: interface, vhdl, fpga, ram, vivado

I'm trying to use the DDR3 memory component on my Arty board (https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/arty/reference-manual?redirect=1), which have the MT41K128M16JT-125 memory part from Micron.

The FPGA is an Artix-7 xc7a35ticsg324-1L.

I've implemented my project in VHDL, and have been using the MIG IP to generate an example project, from which I have written my own "top_level.vhd"-file.

In the "top_level.vhd"-file, the components `UART_RX` and `UART_TX` are for transmitting bytes of data using the UART, and the component `mig_7series_o`, have been generated by the MIG tool.

I've split my question up into smaller segments:

1) As far as I have understood it, the MIG will generate the clock signals itself, and supply me with a clock signal `ui_clk`, which in my code is called `clk`.

But when the code is synthesized, I suspect that the clock signal does not work as it should, and this leads my whole design to not work at all. Could anyone give me an idea on how to make the clock work as it should?

2) Furthermore I can't simulate my design, as I don't have a model for the RAM, but as far as I've understood it, my design would have to be in Verilog, in order to use Microns RAM simulation models, which it is not. This have lead me to the situation, that I have to synthesize the design in order to check if it works, which makes debugging it quite hard.

3) Or is there perhaps someone out there, who have a working interface on the arty board (Or a similar board), who would be so kind to share the module for interfacing with the DDR3 RAM?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity top_level is
    Port ( 
        -- Inouts
       ddr3_dq                        : inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
       ddr3_dqs_p                     : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       ddr3_dqs_n                     : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

       -- Outputs
       ddr3_addr                      : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
       ddr3_ba                        : out   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
       ddr3_ras_n                     : out   std_logic;
       ddr3_cas_n                     : out   std_logic;
       ddr3_we_n                      : out   std_logic;
       ddr3_reset_n                   : out   std_logic;
       ddr3_ck_p                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
       ddr3_ck_n                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
       ddr3_cke                       : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
       ddr3_cs_n                      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
       ddr3_dm                        : out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       ddr3_odt                       : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);

       -- Inputs
       -- Differential system clocks
       sys_clk_p                      : in    std_logic;
       sys_clk_n                      : in    std_logic;
       -- differential iodelayctrl clk (reference clock)
       clk_ref_p                                : in    std_logic;
       clk_ref_n                                : in    std_logic;

       tg_compare_error              : out std_logic;
       init_calib_complete           : out std_logic;

       -- System reset - Default polarity of sys_rst pin is Active Low.
       -- System reset polarity will change based on the option 
       -- selected in GUI.
          sys_rst                     : in    std_logic;
        led1        : out std_logic;
        led2        : out std_logic;
        but         : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        rx_bit      : in std_logic;
        tx_bit      : out std_logic
        --test_clock  : in std_logic
        );
end top_level;

architecture Behavioral of top_level is

component UART_RX
      generic (
        g_CLKS_PER_BIT : integer := 723   -- Needs to be set correctly
      );
      port (
        i_Clk       : in  std_logic;
        i_RX_Serial : in  std_logic;
        o_RX_DV     : out std_logic;
        o_RX_Byte   : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
        );
end component; 

component UART_TX
    generic (
      g_CLKS_PER_BIT : integer := 723   -- Needs to be set correctly
      );
    port (
      i_Clk       : in  std_logic;
      i_TX_DV     : in  std_logic;
      i_TX_Byte   : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      o_TX_Active : out std_logic;
      o_TX_Serial : out std_logic;
      o_TX_Done   : out std_logic
    );
end component;

component mig_7series_0
    port(
      ddr3_dq       : inout std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      ddr3_dqs_p    : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      ddr3_dqs_n    : inout std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

      ddr3_addr     : out   std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
      ddr3_ba       : out   std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      ddr3_ras_n    : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_cas_n    : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_we_n     : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_reset_n  : out   std_logic;
      ddr3_ck_p     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_ck_n     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_cke      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_cs_n     : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      ddr3_dm       : out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
      ddr3_odt      : out   std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
      app_addr                  : in    std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);
      app_cmd                   : in    std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
      app_en                    : in    std_logic;
      app_wdf_data              : in    std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
      app_wdf_end               : in    std_logic;
      app_wdf_mask         : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      app_wdf_wren              : in    std_logic;
      app_rd_data               : out   std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
      app_rd_data_end           : out   std_logic;
      app_rd_data_valid         : out   std_logic;
      app_rdy                   : out   std_logic;
      app_wdf_rdy               : out   std_logic;
      app_sr_req                : in    std_logic;
      app_ref_req               : in    std_logic;
      app_zq_req                : in    std_logic;
      app_sr_active             : out   std_logic;
      app_ref_ack               : out   std_logic;
      app_zq_ack                : out   std_logic;
      ui_clk                    : out   std_logic;
      ui_clk_sync_rst           : out   std_logic;
      init_calib_complete       : out   std_logic;
      -- System Clock Ports
      sys_clk_p                      : in    std_logic;
      sys_clk_n                      : in    std_logic;
      -- Reference Clock Ports
      clk_ref_p                                : in    std_logic;
      clk_ref_n                                : in    std_logic;
      device_temp     : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
      sys_rst             : in std_logic
      );
  end component mig_7series_0;

constant DATA_WIDTH            : integer := 32;
constant PAYLOAD_WIDTH         : integer := DATA_WIDTH;
constant nCK_PER_CLK            : integer := 4;
constant ADDR_WIDTH : integer := 28;
constant APP_DATA_WIDTH : integer := 2*nCK_PER_CLK * PAYLOAD_WIDTH;
constant APP_MASK_WIDTH        : integer := APP_DATA_WIDTH / 8;
signal app_addr                    : std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal init_calib_complete_i       : std_logic;
signal device_temp                           : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
signal app_cmd                     : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal app_en                      : std_logic;
signal app_rdy                     : std_logic;
signal app_wdf_data                : std_logic_vector(APP_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal app_wdf_end                 : std_logic;
signal app_ref_ack                 : std_logic;
signal app_zq_ack                  : std_logic;
signal app_wdf_wren                : std_logic;
signal app_rd_data                 : std_logic_vector(APP_DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal app_rd_data_end             : std_logic;
signal app_rd_data_valid           : std_logic;
signal app_wdf_mask                : std_logic_vector(APP_MASK_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal app_wdf_rdy                 : std_logic;
signal app_sr_active               : std_logic;
signal clk                         : std_logic;


--Mine signaler
type state_type is (reset, init, idle, prep_write, do_write, do_wait_after_write, prep_read, do_read, do_wait_after_read, clean_up, end_state);
signal state : state_type;

type init_state_type is (step1, step2, step3, step4);
signal init_state : init_state_type;
signal init_count : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;


constant c_CLKS_PER_BIT : integer := 723;
signal tx_done, rx_dv, tx_active, tx_dv, wait_for_tx_done, wait_for_but_release : STD_LOGIC;
signal tx_byte, rx_byte : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal count : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;
signal data_read : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal first_init : std_logic := '1';

signal sys_rst_test, rst : std_logic := '1';


begin

x2: UART_RX generic map (
              g_CLKS_PER_BIT => c_CLKS_PER_BIT
              )
      port map( i_Clk => clk,
                i_RX_Serial => rx_bit,
                o_RX_DV => rx_dv,
                o_RX_Byte => rx_byte);

x3: UART_TX generic map (
                  g_CLKS_PER_BIT => c_CLKS_PER_BIT
                  )
       port map(   i_Clk => clk,
                i_TX_DV => tx_dv,
                i_TX_Byte => tx_byte,
                o_TX_Active => tx_active,
                o_TX_Serial => tx_bit,
                o_TX_Done => tx_done);

u_mig_7series_0 : mig_7series_0
      port map (
       -- Memory interface ports
       ddr3_addr                      => ddr3_addr,
       ddr3_ba                        => ddr3_ba,
       ddr3_cas_n                     => ddr3_cas_n,
       ddr3_ck_n                      => ddr3_ck_n,
       ddr3_ck_p                      => ddr3_ck_p,
       ddr3_cke                       => ddr3_cke,
       ddr3_ras_n                     => ddr3_ras_n,
       ddr3_reset_n                   => ddr3_reset_n,
       ddr3_we_n                      => ddr3_we_n,
       ddr3_dq                        => ddr3_dq,
       ddr3_dqs_n                     => ddr3_dqs_n,
       ddr3_dqs_p                     => ddr3_dqs_p,
       init_calib_complete  => init_calib_complete_i,
       device_temp                    => device_temp,
       ddr3_cs_n                      => ddr3_cs_n,
       ddr3_dm                        => ddr3_dm,
       ddr3_odt                       => ddr3_odt,
-- Application interface ports
       app_addr                       => app_addr,
       app_cmd                        => app_cmd,
       app_en                         => app_en,
       app_wdf_data                   => app_wdf_data,
       app_wdf_end                    => app_wdf_end,
       app_wdf_wren                   => app_wdf_wren,
       app_rd_data                    => app_rd_data,
       app_rd_data_end                => app_rd_data_end,
       app_rd_data_valid              => app_rd_data_valid,
       app_rdy                        => app_rdy,
       app_wdf_rdy                    => app_wdf_rdy,
       app_sr_req                     => '0',
       app_ref_req                    => '0',
       app_zq_req                     => '0',
       app_sr_active                  => app_sr_active,
       app_ref_ack                    => app_ref_ack,
       app_zq_ack                     => app_zq_ack,
       ui_clk                         => clk,
       ui_clk_sync_rst                => rst,
       app_wdf_mask                   => app_wdf_mask,
-- System Clock Ports
       sys_clk_p                       => sys_clk_p,
       sys_clk_n                       => sys_clk_n,
-- Reference Clock Ports
       clk_ref_p                      => clk_ref_p,
       clk_ref_n                      => clk_ref_n,
        sys_rst                        => sys_rst
        );

process(clk)
begin
--    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
--        if(but(0) = '1') then
--            rst <= '1';
--        end if;
--    end if;
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        case(state) is
            when reset =>
                --rst <= '1';
                led1 <= '0';
                led2 <= '0';
                state <= init;
            when init =>
                led2 <= '1';
--                if(count > 20) then
--                    rst <= '0';
--                else
--                    count <= count + 1;
--                    rst <= '1';
--                end if;
                --rst <= '0';
                app_en <= '0';
                app_wdf_end <= '0';
                app_wdf_wren <= '0';
                app_addr <= (others => '0');
                app_cmd <= (others => '0');
                app_wdf_data <= (others => '0');
                app_wdf_mask <= (others => '0');
                if(init_calib_complete_i = '1') then
                    --led2 <= '1';
                    state <= idle;
                end if;
            when idle =>
                led1 <= '1';
                --led2 <= '1';
                tx_dv <= '1';
                tx_byte <= X"47";
                state <= end_state;
            when end_state =>
                --led1 <= '1';
                --led2 <= '1';
                tx_dv <= '0';
            when others =>
                state <= idle;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: 1) You don't provide enough information to help. There's nothing in your VHDL code to show how the clocks are generated or how anything else works. Output  a clk to a pin so you can check with a scope. 2) The [Verilog DRAM model](https://www.micron.com/parts/dram/ddr3-sdram/mt41k128m16jt-125) could be translated by hand to VHDL if you don't have a mixed language simulation license (it's big but looks straight forward). For 1), 2) and 3), see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The question isn't on-topic as is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
1) As far as I have understood it, the MIG IP core should generate the clock signals, that is the reason why I don't have any code showing how the clocks are generated. I can output the ui_clk to an external port, but using the scope, I can see, that it is at a constant 0V. 
If I try to output sys_clk_p or clk_ref_p, I get the message from the implementation, that it is a dedicated connection.
2) I was kind of hoping that I did not have to translate the DRAM model, since I have no experience with verilog.

Comment: What is the input reference clock frequency you have set during configuration? What is the `sys_rst` polarity? Check if the MIG IP is always held in reset. Check the `mmcm_locked` and the `init_calib_complete` signals too to be sure.